# Share Intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter

Is it possible to share a video in twitter using android native sharing intent?

So far, it is what I have in my code which twitter is not letting me to share videos.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
intent.setType("*/*");
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
final List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
 int len =  activityList.size();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
final ResolveInfo app = (ResolveInfo) activityList.get(i);
                if (app.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(appName) || 
                        app.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(appName)) {
                    final ActivityInfo activity=app.activityInfo;
                    final ComponentName name=new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName, 
                            activity.name);
                    intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                    intent.setComponent(name);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,      "sample message");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,    Uri.fromFile(file));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: in SO, typically you should mention your specific problem in your code..

Comment: Oops, my bad, I have edited my question. twitter just returns a message "Unable to load image".